# My countdown only drops by 1 and no more, why is that?

Tags: java, countdown

So , i want to create a countdown for a user inputed date in a service class.Right now i have problems with the countdown.It seems no matter what it only substracts 1 second and doesn't go further.Here is the code:

the logic for the countdown

```
package com.example.service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class CounterService {
    LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime(){
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime parseDate(String eventDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(eventDate, formatter);
        return dateTime;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CounterService cs = new CounterService();
        LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.of(2021,11,11,21,43,44);
        cs.setDateTime(a);

        Runnable r = new Counter(cs);
        new Thread(r).start();

    }
}
```

and the Runnable

```
package com.example.service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Counter implements Runnable {
    CounterService counter;

    public Counter(CounterService cs) {
        this.counter = cs;
    }

    public void setCounter(CounterService cs) {
        this.counter = cs;
    }

    public void run() {
        LocalDateTime countFromThisDate = counter.getDateTime();
        try {
            boolean x = true;
            while (x) {
                LocalDateTime substracting = countFromThisDate.minusSeconds(1);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(substracting);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

also how will i be able to add this counter (after it works) so that it refreshes dynamically and substracts each second one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` is immutable.

`countFromThisDate.minusSeconds(1)` returns a new instance, it does not update the instance it is called upon. You'd need to assign the result back to somewhere (for example by calling `setDateTime` on your service).

This works just like as it does with `String`.

That service also needs to be made thread-safe (for this, you should probably move the substraction logic into the service itself, so that it can become atomic instead of get/subtract/set).

Comment: ok i see . I did that and i get the same issue.  So i added counter.setDateTime(substracting); right before Thread.sleep(1000); and it still substracts only 1 second and then it loops over and over the same result.Can you help me with some code please?

Comment: Ok , seems i needed to move just 1 line of code to make it work.Thanks Alot !

Answer (score 1):

Stating an implementation flaw here - Thread.sleep doesn't guarantee that the thread is run after the passed interval, it just makes the thread state *ready* (to be run by cpu) after the interval. Instead, you should use the system time to get the time elapsed since the counter start.

**-- UPDATE --**

A small change in your CounterService will do the work. CounterService will also keep a startTime besides the countdown datetime. The code will look something like below -

```
class CounterService {      

    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    public CounterService(LocalDateTime dateTime, LocalDateTime startTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCounterTime() {
        return dateTime.minusSeconds(startTime.until(LocalDateTime.now(), ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.of(2021,11,11,21,43,44);
        LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        final CounterService counterService = new CounterService(a, startTime);

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(counterService.getCounterTime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, could you please give an example with code relating to my situation?

Comment: ok, that seems a good way to do it.Btw what i need to do after this, is send the countdown timer back to the user, can you also help me with that?

Comment: Actually, I didn't get your use case. The question is - why your countdown timer is returning subtracted datetime instead of a relative time until the datetime (like xx days xx hours xx mins... remaining for given datetime)?

Comment: now countdown is working correctly but i need to find a way to use it in a servlet jsp and show it in a webpage